# sendmail with thousands of queued mails and deferred 451 4.3.2 inside logfile

Tags: sendmail

I am running sendmail on ubuntu 14.04 in combination with OpenEMM 2015. While sendmail is running, it does not seem to send out mails. I checked the mail queue and there are loads of mails lined up:

```
:/etc/mail$ mailq | more 
MSP Queue status...
    /var/spool/mqueue-client (1600 requests)
```

Those might be not even enough, as OpenEMM has generated within a first newsletter 20K e-mails (to double opt in subscribed users by the way) that have not been sent out for some reason. Additionally there might be loads of system emails hanging, like registration e-mails etc.

mail.log tells me thousands of lines similar to this one:

```
Dec 29 15:40:25 fx3 sm-msp-queue[18770]: tBOK01TQ016591: to=postmaster, delay=4+18:40:16, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31001045, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: 451 4.3.2 Please try again later
```

The install guide to OpenEMM says the following:

> IMPORTANT: If you use AppArmor with SuSE, it requires the following entries for the file

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.sendmail :
/home/openemm/var/spool/ADMIN rwl,
/home/openemm/var/spool/ADMIN/* rwl,
/home/openemm/var/spool/QUEUE rwl,
/home/openemm/var/spool/QUEUE/* rwl,
```

Otherwise, Sendmail will not be able to communicate with OpenEMM. Unfortunatelly this file is not present on ubunutu, BUT AppArmor is active.

The system is a pretty fresh set up so it is highly likely that I have not configured everything OK which now needs to be fixed.

What might be causing this and how could I track to down the problem further? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Check your logs for _other_ entries which indicate what is failing.

Comment: To elaborate on Michael Hampton's comment, the log line you show if for an error mail sent to postmaster. That that error mail does not arrive is in itself an indication that something is misconfigured, but that misconfiguration is another one than the one that is stopping you from sending out mails.